# How to go out of the conditional IF statement? Return doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, return, control-flow

I have an example of a class. It creates a new card and puts it into the array. I want to control the number of cards and leave the flow if the number of cards is more than 54:

```
public class Card {
    private final String rank; 
    private final String suit;
    private String[][] cards;
    private static int NoC = 0;

    public Card(String suit, String rank) {
        if (NoC >= 54) {
        System.out.println("You cannot create any more cards");

        // and this "return" doesn't work correctly. NetBeans says "variable rank might not have been initialized"
        return;   
    }

    this.suit = suit;
    this.rank = rank;

    cards = new String[54][2];
    cards[NoC][0] = this.suit;
    cards[NoC][1] = this.rank;
    NoC = NoC + 1;
}
```

The program is compiled without errors. And works as I expect: if 55th card is being created it goes to the `IF` clause and prints the notice "You cannot create any more cards", but also it throws a warning *"Uncompilable source code - variable rank might not have been initialized"*.

How to make it run correctly? Do I have to use smth else instead of `return` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to prevent a 53rd card being created, you can't just `return` from the constructor -  that would result in an improperly constructed object without the client noticing anything (how should the direct caller of the constructor know what was printed to stdout?). Instead, you need to throw an *exception*:

```
public Card(String suit, String rank) {
    if (NoC >= 52) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("You cannot create any more cards");
    }

    this.suit = suit;
    this.rank = rank;

    cards = new String[54][2];
    cards[NoC][0] = this.suit;
    cards[NoC][1] = this.rank;
    NoC = NoC + 1;
}
```

`IllegalStateException` is just an example here - an existing runtime exception which you might reuse for this purpose. Or you may prefer defining and using your own (checked) exception instead.

#### A better solution

In general defining a type whose values are statically known and restricted, is best done using an `enum`. This avoids the whole problem above, because it is not possible to construct new `enum` values dynamically, so there is no need to check anything.

Comment: Thank you. And what if it wouldn't be a constructor but just a usual method? Would the return command work correctly then?

Comment: @Green, if there is no field initialization taking place inside the method, then yes. However, you need to think it through from the caller's perspective too. Is calling this method too many times a) an exceptional, showstopper problem or a programmatic error which must be handled directly (possibly by aborting execution), or b) can it be dealt with switftly or silently ignored and the normal execution flow continued? In case a), you should throw an exception. In b), you may return (possibly an error flag).

Answer (score 3):

throw an `IllegalArgumentException` in your constructor instead of Sysout & return.
Since this is an exceptional case, ie, the constructor cannot create the class instance with such a value, simply returning normally from the constructor makes the program continue normally, which you dont want in this case, so throwing an exception is the most appropriate thing to do here.

Comment: IMHO `IllegalArgumentException` is not a good choice here, as the problem is not caused by an invalid argument.

Comment: I think "invalidity of an argument" is subjective, I believe `IllegalStateException` or `IllegalArgumentException` or `ExceptionInInitializationError` could be used depending on the use case & of course readability.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return from a constructor. What you should do to prevent the creation is to throw an exception from the constructor:

```
 public Card(String suit, String rank) {
    if (NoC >= 52) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("The limit has been reached");
    }
    ...
 }
```